# JSON file accessible without module exports

Tags: node.js, requirejs, node-modules

In one tutorial, the author said the "require" function can execute other files but it doesn't have access to other file's function and variable Unless they are exported by using module exports.

but if the file is JSON, it is exported default. Other files have access without module exports. Why?

For example,

> index.js

```
let app = require('./app');
let greetings = require('./greetings.json');
console.log('greetings', greetings); // Won't throw error
app.greet(); // throw Error
```

> app.js

```
    function greet() {
       console.log('hello')
    }
    greet()
```

> greetings.json

```
{
   english: "Hello",
   spanish: "Hola"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are calling the function greet in the app.js not exporting it, as such you can not access the method. You have loaded the app file but did not tell the modules what can be accessed from it. The file on the other side is loaded as a whole.

so if you would export the greet function as default or a part of the modules

```
module.exports = greet
```

that would make it available for calling.

Comment: I think I mentioned all these in my question.
My question is why calling greet() without exports is throwing an error but greetings JSON value is not throwing error

Comment: Like I said from your code the following should happen.
You should get a Hello as you required the app.js and called the greet() there.
You load up the whole json file, it exists as object not as a function now in your index.js
You will log the contenct of the Json file as you have loaded it.
You get an error as you are calling a 'private' function from the app.js. If you want to access anything from the app.js you have to export it. Until you do so, it is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the CommonJS modules are working. You have to specify what you want to be a public of your module. Rest of it you might want to be private, not visible outside. I think this is good architectural decision to make all private except things you want to be private. That makes the code more safe.

But the JSON you gave, it is the representation of the data, so why you would like it to have private / public parts?